# Auto ajust and fit width items on using weight

Tags: android, android-layout

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have to display multiples rows.
Each row has an internal weight: the description has a specific weight, the price, and so on.

In the following pictures, you can see two kind of screenshot. The first one shows each row perfectly.

The second one, some prices not fit correctly.

**Picture 1:**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Picture 2:**

[image: Screenshot 2]

This my row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:maxHeight="24dp"
            android:maxWidth="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:text="$"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**WHAT I NEED:**

Is there any possibility to auto adjust the prices?

- May be change the size of the text.
- May be change the weight automatically.

¿What is the **best practice** for soliving this kind of problem? Changing the size I really don't like because will be some text with one size and text with other size

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. In addition, "what is the best practice" questions are opinion based and therefore attract opinionated answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as I see the first Linear is fixed with the same data and the second one is making the problem, the way you are using weight is a little bit wrong, you need to set the width of the second linear to `wrap_content` with no weight and set the width of the first linear to `0dp` and the weight equals 1, so your layout will take the width of the second linear and the rest will be token by the first one.

Comment: And if I have 3 linears instead of two? which one I need to put the weight and which one I have to put wrap_content?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between using weight like you said, and set each LinearLayout to wrap_content and set one with gravity left and the other one with gravity right?

Comment: there is a lot of choices you can make I'm just answering your question about the way you used weight you need to look for other answer your own. if you use 3 linears you set weight = 1 to the one that you need to take the not token space